# How to identify failed test cases in fastlane scan for rerunning?

Tags: ruby, junit, xcodebuild, fastlane

As part of adding XCode's UI Tests to our CI flow, I've decided to implement re-running failed tests before failing the build, due to the general unreliability of the test framework.

I can avoid failing the build immediately by using a `rescue` block, that's not a problem, and the location of the report files (JUnit and HTML) is fixed, so that can be opened with eg File.readlines.

The format of the junit report file is a cascade of testsuites -> testsuite -> testcase -> failure message if applicable, and then back out far enough for the next element. Seems pretty standard.

However, at that point I'm a little stuck (and it may not be the right path; is there a canonical better way to do this in the first place?). In bash I'd use grep -B to pull out the line before the failure message, which would be the name of the failing test case, then grab the relevant text snippet using awk. Easy two pipe shell command that I can then feed back into scan/xcodebuild using the -only-testing parameter.

Is there a way to do this with equivalent ease in Ruby, or a junit plugin that will let me read out nothing but the names of the individual failing test cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case someone runs into this question sometime in the future:

```
  def parse_ui_test_report
doc = File.open("#{REPORT_LOCATION}/report.junit") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }
node_tree = doc.css('testcase')
test_identifiers_to_rerun = node_tree.map do |node|
  # Test case nodes in the JUNIT XML doc don't have children unless they failed
  if node.first_element_child
    node.values.join('/').gsub('.','/')
  end
end.select {|str| !str.nil? && !str.empty? }

return test_identifiers_to_rerun
end
```